# Ubuntu 16.04 correct way to specify a directory / folder using terminal chown to recursively change ownership / permissions

Tags: command-line, directory, lamp, xampp, paths

OK - so I open terminal and I want to use chown to change permissions / ownership recursively.  I want to use

```
sudo chown -R username:group directory
```

The folder I want to change permissions on is opt/lampp what would be the correct replacement for 'directory' to change permissions on opt/lampp - if the following was my command to recursively replace ownership on the parent directory all subfolders and all files for the lampp directory and I am a sudo user, the command would be

```
sudo chown -R myname:sudo what goes here ?
```

please tell me what I would enter in terminal instead of 'what goes here'

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest you first cd to /opt and then run `sudo chown -R username:group ./lammp` If you miss the space between / and opt when running chown, thatll be bad, so it's better to cd first

Comment: @Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy Perfect !!! Please post as answer and I can accept - cheers mate !

Comment: OK. Turned my common into a full answer

Comment: Please explain why you want this? Software in /opt/ is installed by unpacking a tar file. Tar has this inherent feature of maintaining permissions so there should be no reason for you to mess with the permissions. The software in /opt/ should be as is (set to "root:root"). You use a "service" to create access to the software. ALL user related content for a LAMP server should be outside of /opt/ (probably /var/www/).

Comment: @Rinzwind - thanks for taking the interest to explore my reasons.  Sergiy answered my question correctly which helped to educate me.

Comment: @Rinzwind My reason for asking is that I have Xampp installed - everything was fine but now MySQL has stopped working and PHPMyadmin gives a permissions error - I have had problems with permissions lately.  I thought this may be a solution.  This did not solve my initial problem but helped me rule out one option and helped me learn about folders and permissions - so he did answer my initial question - but maybe I need to ask another

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest you first `cd /opt` and then run `sudo chown -R username:group ./lammp` .

The reason for that is simple:  if you by accident add space between `/` and `opt` when running `sudo chown -R username:group /opt/lammp` , that'll be bad. In fact this is a common error we see on Ask Ubuntu a lot - new users do this mistake by accident and as a result their system becomes extremely difficult to recover. Thus , `cd` first, `chown` second

Comment: I disagree. The whole idea for software in /opt/ is for it to be owned by ROOT and where you use a service to start and stop this software (and that service is owned by root too).

Comment: @Rinzwind not necessarily owned by root. Consider a particular application which may be have to be owned a non-login user. Webservers like Apache use `www` user, if my memory is correct. While for the most part items in /opt *should* be owned by root, it's not always  needed. Besides, I'm merely giving the user what they asked for. The question isn't about what should and shouldn't be done

Comment: The only file when you install apache in /opt/ that needs to be owned by the user would be the "my.cnf" file and when installing in /opt/ that file should be created in `/home/$USER`. Installing in /opt/ is done through a tar file and the maintainer already set all the permissions as they should be. Any change to that is setting security lower than needed (especially when dealing with a website hosted on your machine).

Comment: OK, I can agree with that

Comment: Thank you all - I understand what you are saying - my initial problem is different cause to what I expected but Rinzwind did answer my actual question which helped educate me - so I will accept his answer but appreciate people thinking outside the box and asking why and giving me ideas and reasons to think differently - thanks guys - all of you